# XAMPP: Mysql failing to start linux

Tags: mysql, linux, database, xampp

I'm trying to start Mysql under XAMPP in linux with the following command

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server start
```

But I get the following result

```
.2017-03-02 01:05:00 3447 mysqld_safe Logging to '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/user.err'.
[F failed!
```

This is the user.err

```
2017-03-02 01:05:00 3447 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/lampp/var/mysql
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'key_buffer' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'key_buffer_size' instead.
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] /opt/lampp/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.19-MariaDB) starting as process 3594 ...
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-03-02  1:05:00 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-03-02  1:05:01 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.32-79.0 started; log sequence number 1769504
2017-03-02  1:05:01 140306716243776 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 1 !!!
2017-03-02  1:05:01 140306408351488 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-03-02  1:05:01 140306716243776 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-03-02  1:05:01 140306716243776 [Note] Recovering after a crash using tc.log
2017-03-02  1:05:01 140306716243776 [ERROR] Can't init tc log
2017-03-02  1:05:01 140306716243776 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-03-02 01:05:03 3447 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/lampp/var/mysql/user.pid ended
```

I've already tried to delete the `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/arialog*` file and the `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/ib_logfile*` file, but without results

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can help other people. I've solved the problem deleting the tc.log file in `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/`. After that I've started mysql again, that created the tc.log itself.